# Create grouping that includes missing keys

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have an `IEnumerable<T>` that has a `Created` field, which is a date.
There can be multiple `T`'s per date and sometimes there are no `T`'s for a given date.

Currently I'm grouping these by the date, which gives me all the dates that have at least one `T`, and the `T`'s under them.

What I want though, is something I can use as part of a query that will get me all dates within a range, regardless of whether there are any `T`'s with the given date.

Current Code:

```
var adjustments = DAL.GetAdjustmentsInDateRange(Start, End);

from adjustment in adjustments
group adjustment by adjustment.Created.Date into adjustmentsByDay
orderby adjustmentsByDay.Key descending
select ....
```

Here, **`adjustmentsByDay` doesn't have all dates between `Start` and `End`. What I want is for it to include them, with no elements.**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a general-purpose LINQ-to-objects extension method to insert missing things into a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> InsertMissing<T, U>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, U> key, Func<U, U> increment, Func<U, T> create)
{
    bool first = true;
    U last = default(U);

    foreach (var ig in source)
    {
        U current = key(ig);

        if (first)
        {
            first = false;
            last = current;
            yield return ig;
            continue;
        }

        while (!(last = increment(last)).Equals(current))
        {
            yield return create(last);
        }

        yield return ig;
    }
}
```

You'll also need a custom implementation of `IGrouping`:

```
class EmptyGrouping<K, E> : IGrouping<K, E> {
    public K Key { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<E> GetEnumerator() {
        return Enumerable.Empty<E>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return this.GetEnumerator(); 
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to end your query after the `orderby`, follow it with this call, and then put your `select` afterwards:

```
var allGroups = query.InsertMissing(
    // Key selector
    g => g.Key,
    // Get next desired key from current key
    d => d.AddDays(-1),
    // Create item for missing key
    d => new EmptyGrouping<DateTime,YourAdjustmentType>{ Key = d });
```

This *will* go haywire if your keys aren't ordered or if one of them doesn't fall in the correct place (e.g. in your case, isn't on midnight).

This has the advantage of not needing multiple queries on the original source to determine the min/max values in order to generate a list of keys, and then a further query to join and get the data.

Comment: Great! Gotta love query extensions.

Answer (score 2):

You could left join adjustments with a list of all dates before grouping, like so:

```
var adjustments = DAL.GetAdjustmentsInDateRange(Start, End);
// Get all unique dates in time span
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = GetAllDates(Start, End); 

var query = (from date in dates
                join adjustment in adjustments
                    on date.Date equals adjustment.Created.Date into a
                from adjustment in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new {date.Date, adjustment}
                ).GroupBy(i=>i.Date).OrderBy(g=>g.Key);
```

Comment: That looks good, but at the moment I get an error on the group by line, because `adjustment` is `null` (I've left that line and below the same).

Comment: Sorry if there is a syntax error. Refer to the Linq 101, left outer join is the very last example: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I now updated my answer, but the group and order by is in method syntax and not query syntax. This solution works for me, assuming you can first create a list of all Dates betweet `Start` and `End`